# Python: draw circle with interactive gui?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote a python script with mathplotlib.
I have 3 sliders "r1", "r2", "dist".

r1 is the radius for circle 1.
r2 is the radius for circle 2.
dist is the distance between circle 1 and 2.

Now I want to print two circles.
The 1. circles radius should have the value of slider r1.
The 2. circles radius should have the value of slider r2.
And the distance between the two circles in the x axis should be the value of slider dist.

For me it is no problem to draw this things.
But when I move the slider, the circles don't move/change.

How can I implement 2 interactive circles with python that I can manage the radius and the distance with the sliders???

What I have till now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 100])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
sl1 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sl2 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sl3 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

slider_r1 = Slider(sl1, 'r1', 0.0, 50.0, 25)
slider_r2 = Slider(sl2, 'r2', 0.0, 50.0, 25)
slider_d = Slider(sl3, 'dist', 0.0, 50.0, 25)



def update(val):
    print("\nr1: ",slider_r1.val)
    print("r2: ",slider_r2.val)
    print("dist: ", slider_d.val)

slider_r1.on_changed(update)
slider_r2.on_changed(update)
slider_d.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't see any code to draw circles.

Answer (score 1):

A circle can be created via [`circle = plt.circle((x,y), radius)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle) and added to the axes using `ax.add_patch(cicle)`.

Its radius can be updated by `circle.set_radius` and its center can be set as `circle.center = x,y` <sub>(unfortunately it doesn't have a `set_position` or `set_xy`. method like other artist).</sub>

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
ax.axis([0, 100, 0, 100])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

axcolor = 'skyblue'
sl1 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sl2 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
sl3 = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

slider_r1 = Slider(sl1, 'r1', 0.0, 50.0, 25)
slider_r2 = Slider(sl2, 'r2', 0.0, 50.0, 25)
slider_d = Slider(sl3, 'dist', 0.0, 100.0, 50)

circ1 = plt.Circle((25,50), 25, ec="k")
circ2 = plt.Circle((75,50), 25, ec="k")
ax.add_patch(circ1)
ax.add_patch(circ2)

def update(val):
    r1 = slider_r1.val
    r2 = slider_r2.val
    d  = slider_d.val
    circ1.center = 50-d/2., 50
    circ2.center = 50+d/2., 50
    circ1.set_radius(r1) 
    circ2.set_radius(r2)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider_r1.on_changed(update)
slider_r2.on_changed(update)
slider_d.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]